# Can I query exactly the result

Tags: sql

i have a problem as below.
In table i have a code field with

```
----id----code---name
| 28700 | 1    | 222           
| 28813 | 001  | 1111
```

The code field is a string field on table

```
code           | varchar(20)         | NO   |     | NULL              |
```

right now i want to get the record have code 1 (not 001, 0001 only just code = 1)
i have added condition where code = 1 in sql but it always return the record has code is 1 or 01 or 001.
so how can i fix it?

Comment: What is your Database Server

Comment: i'm using mysql, sorry i have mistake.  code = "1" it will be returned the exactly result.
Thank you for your response

Answer (score 1):

It is a string, so the comparison needs to be a string:

```
where code = '1'
```

When you use:

```
where code = 1
```

then you are mixing types.  SQL converts the string to a number, and both `'1'` and `'001'` are converted to the same value, `1`.